# Facebook and Youtube not show on Android Activity Chooser

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-activity

My Android app contains links, I want to share this link on Facebook. I used `Intent.ACTION_SEND` but why

Facebook icon is not shown on `Activity Chooser`, my code:

```
        Intent sharing = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        sharing.setType("text/html");

        sharing.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out this video");

        sharing.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoUrl);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharing, "What to share?"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
sharing.setType("text/html");
```

To

```
sharing.setType("text/plain");
```

This modification solved this issue here. Hope it will help you!

Also, check this code that I use to share a link using specific apps: http://pastebin.com/JhYzdL4s.

Comment: This is the code I use to share a text using specific applications, including facebook. It works perfectly here. Other apps appear in the chooser? Maybe your problem is related to Facebook app itself. http://pastebin.com/JhYzdL4s

Comment: @Binngokute I updated my answer, could you please accepted as the correct answer of your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the package for your sharing intent.

For example, if you want to set a Facebook package, you need to do:

```
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
      String packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
        if(packageName.toLowerCase().contains("facebook")) {
            share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
        }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work too, I checked this, but no package contains "facebook", even though facebook app is already installed

Comment: maybe you need to convert the package name to lowercase. Please check my edited code.